# Lapply over subset of dataframes without splitting further

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I am at a loss on how to do this without addressing each individual part. I have an initial timeseries dataset that I split into a list of 12 dataframes representing each month. Within each month, I want to run calculations and ggplot on each unique site without having to call each individual site. The structure currently is as follows:

```
 $ April    :'data.frame':  9360 obs. of  15 variables:
  ..$ site_id     : int [1:9360] 1003 1003 1003 1003 1003 1003 1003 1003 1003 1003 ...
  ..$ UTC_date.1  : Date[1:9360], format: "2005-04-01" "2005-04-02" "2005-04-03" "2005-04-04" ...
  ..$ POSIXct     : POSIXct[1:9360], format: "2005-04-01 06:00:00" "2005-04-02 06:00:00" "2005-04-03 06:00:00" "2005-04-04 06:00:00" ...
  ..$ swe_mm      : num [1:9360] 45.9 44.6 43.5 42.4 41.2 ...
  ..$ fsca        : num [1:9360] 1 1 1 1 0.997 ...
  ..$ snoht_m     : num [1:9360] 0.303 0.239 0.21 0.186 0.165 ...
  ..$ swe_mm.1    : num [1:9360] 45.9 44.6 43.5 42.4 41.2 ...
  ..$ fsca.1      : num [1:9360] 1 1 1 1 0.997 ...
  ..$ snoht_m.1   : num [1:9360] 0.303 0.239 0.21 0.186 0.165 ...
  ..$ actSWE_mm   : num [1:9360] 279 282 282 282 282 284 292 295 295 295 ...
  ..$ actSD_cm    : num [1:9360] 79 79 NA 79 79 81 185 81 81 81 ...
  ..$ swe_Res_mm  : num [1:9360] 233 237 238 240 241 ...
  ..$ snoht_Res_m : num [1:9360] 0.487 0.551 NA 0.604 0.625 ...
  ..$ swe_Res1_mm : num [1:9360] 233 237 238 240 241 ...
  ..$ snoht_Res1_m: num [1:9360] 0.487 0.551 NA 0.604 0.625 ...
```

I can use lapply to calculate the standardized rmse without issue if I apply it to each dataframe entirely:

```
stdres.fun <- function(data,x,out) {data[out] <- data[[x]] / ((sum(data[[x]]^2, na.rm = TRUE)/NROW(data))^.5); data}
monthSplit <- lapply(monthSplit, stdres.fun, x = "swe_Res_mm", out="stdSWE_res")
```

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to run this calculation on each unique site_id. What I mean to say is there are 32 different sites. They are the same sites in each dataframe, however I want to calculate the rmse for each site within each dataframe in the list.  So if I had sites 946 and 1003, the calculation would run on each of those separately rather than together.

I'm assuming I can split the data further into different lists but I feel like this would be messier than it already is. Is there another way I can go about doing this?

Comment: This is a case were a repreducible example would go a long way, can you share the output of `dput()` or `dput(head())` of your data?

Comment: I tried, but the output is too long for the console window so it cuts off. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could modify the function and use `tidyverse` methods

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
monthSplit2 <- map(monthSplit, ~ 
             .x %>%
                group_by(sites) %>%
                mutate(stdSWE_res = swe_Res_mm/((sum(swe_Res_mm^2, 
                na.rm = TRUE)/n()) ^.5))
```

Comment: I went over the documentation for mutate, but I still don't quite understand it. Could you explain what it actually does in  the above? As in what would be the difference between using mutate above versus just calculating stdSWE_res directly?

Comment: @user3427325  There is not much difference except that the `NROW` here is replaced by `n()` number of rows which would be different when you are grouping vs not grouping

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I keep getting a : Error: object 'stdSWE_res' not found . I know this column isn't created yet, but I was under the assumption that the column would create itself given the calculation?

Comment: @user3427325 sorry, that is  my mistake in copying the code from your logic.  On the rhs of `=`, it is both `swe_Res_mm`.  Updated the code